# Error installing rails, missing ruby.exe

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I tried to install Rails to my Windows using RailsInstaller from railsinstaller.org.

Everything works just fine, until the moment i use 'gem install rails' and this error code pops up:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: D:/Misc/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nio4r-1.2.1/ext/nio4r
D:/Misc/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160715-720-115hc2e.rb extconf.rb
D:/Misc/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory --extconf.rb (LoadError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in D:/Misc/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nio4r-1.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Misc/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/nio4r-1.2.1/gem_make.out
```

The error still exists even after i installed the x64 version.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: D:/Misc/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-1.2.1/ext/nio4r
D:/Misc/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160715-7956-15ui18c.rb extconf.rb
D:/Misc/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb (LoadError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in D:/Misc/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-1.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/Misc/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/nio4r-1.2.1/gem_make.out
```

I checked the said directory and the file is definitely there. I've tried reinstalling and the result is the same. Also, i know there is a lot of similar question all  around stackoverflow but none of them seems helpful for this problem, so pardon me for asking.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: When you type ruby -v in the command line, what does it say?

Comment: it says "ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]"

Comment: And what is your System Type, listed in system information?

Comment: Mine's x64... So it's because i'm using the 32 bit version, then?

Comment: Ah, when it comes to getting Rails working on windows, it may not be the only issue :). But it is ONE issue. You can get the 64 bit version here. http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/. Install it and then make sure you add it to your environment path so when you type in ruby -v, it says x64 at the end (provably [x64-mingw32]). Then try installing Rails again.

Comment: I've installed the x64 version using rubyinstaller  "ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x64-mingw32]" but when i tried to install rails again, the error is still there, exactly the same.

Comment: Ah, that's rough. Another thing I can think of is it's trying to install a version of Rails that doesn't work with your system. So maybe try something like gem install rails -v 4.1.8 (which is working on my windows setup) or gem install rails -v 4.2.0. Sorry, I wasn't more helpful, I'll keep thinking as I struggle with this kind of thing on Windows all the time. I'm probably about to switch to Ubuntu because Windows is so incompatible.

Comment: Wow.. It worked actually .. thanks a lot for the answers! :D I wonder why things get so complicated though, it works easily in my previous windows laptop :/ Once again thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Nice! Yeah, another day another gem release that only works on Linux. I've had to specify pretty all my gem versions, because every time I bundle install another gem will update and then crash my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, could be a few things. Off the top of my head:

1. Did you accidentally install the 32 bit version of Ruby or Rails when you needed 64 bit?
2. Is the link to D:/Misc/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/ruby.exe in your Environment variable path?
   [image: Environment variable path]
3. Are you installing a version of the Rails Gem that doesn't work well with Windows? or your current system setup. It might be worth trying `gem install rails -v 4.1.8` (which works on my windows setup) or other specific versions and see if one works.

Comment: 1. I'm not too sure about that.. I downloaded the windows installer from railsinstaller.org, there's no 32/64 bit written anywhere..
2. I'm pretty sure it's already in both user and system variables.