# No such directory ruby.exec Errno:ENONT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to ruby on rails.
I installed ruby, sqlite3, node and yarn, run gem install rails and gem install sqlite3.

when I run rails new <app_name>, I got this error.

```
D:/Program Files/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:53:in `exec': No such file or directory - "D:/Program Files/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe" (Errno::ENOENT)
```

How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error installing rails, missing ruby.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387958/error-installing-rails-missing-ruby-exe)

Comment: No I followed it, It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It worked. after reinstall ruby to drive C. (I first installed it in drive D)

Answer (score 1):

You should install it under a path without space, so try to avoid "program files" folder.